# react burger menu displaying menu off screen when closed and in the middle of screen when opened

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, menu

I have implemented the react-burger-menu in my reactjs project. I want to display my react menu not immediately on the left, but next to another column styled component.

```
<Container>
        <LeftContainer style={{background: '#00ff00', width: '400px'}}>
        </LeftContainer>
                  
     <div >
       <Menu disableAutoFocus   customBurgerIcon={ false } isOpen={this.state.YouIsOpen}>
        <a id="home" className="menu-item" href="/">Home</a>
        <a id="about" className="menu-item" href="/about">About</a>
        <a id="contact" className="menu-item" href="/contact">Contact</a>
        <a onClick={ this.showSettings } className="menu-item--small" href="">Settings</a>
      </Menu>
     </div>

</Container>
```

Where the Container element is in columns to display the inner two elements side by side. I want the Menu and LeftContainer to appear side by side where Menu is to the right of the LeftContainer. When the Menu is not open, I dont want to see the menu and I should see the full green LeftContainer, but when it is open, I want to see the red Menu appear to the right of the full green Left Container. However, now, the Menu still shows when it is 'closed' and covers part of the green LeftContainer. It displays correctly when it is opened, I am having issues setting it to display off screen when it is 'closed'

[When menu is open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4uww.png)

[When menu is closed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBekV.png)

Comment: You should create a sandbox for this. Be easier to help you with.

Comment: @Yatrix I dont think I can because the larger project I am incorporatingt this on utilizes some other packages and bootstrap, hopefully the code snippet and pictures will describe the problem. If you copy that code snippet into the Create React App and run it should show you what I mean as well. Please help as this has been an issue I have been trying to figure out for weeks